# Oracle SQL column tweak

Tags: sql, oracle

How could I convert this

[image]

into this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` and a `case` expression:

```
select coalesce(col1, col2) as col3,
       (case when col1 is null then 'Add' else 'Remove' end) as col4
from t
where col1 is null or col2 is null;
```

EDIT:

You should fix your data model.  Until then, you can `cast()`
the values:

```
coalesce(cast(col1 as nvarchar2(255)), cast(col2 as nvarchar2(255))
```

You don't really need to cast both values, but I don't want to remember which column has which type.

Comment: It's throwing this: ORA-12704: character set mismatch
12704. 00000 -  "character set mismatch"

Comment: Columns 
NAME         DATA TYPE             NULL  DEFAULT    COMMENTS
 COL1      VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)   Yes              
 COL2     NVARCHAR2(12)         Yes

Comment: You should fix your data model so the two columns are stored using the same type.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me how coalesce works :)